# Unique Maximal ideal in a ring containing $\Bbb C$ is the nilradical.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This is a question from Algebra (Artin) ex.10.8.8

$R$ is a ring containing $\Bbb C$ as a subring.
Assume $R$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb C$ and that $R$ contains exactly one maximal ideal $M$. Prove that $M$ is the nilradical of $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Since $R$ is finite dimensional, prime ideals are maximal. Hopefully you also know the nilradical is equal to the intersection of prime ideals.